# Load Javascript files through HTML file on WKWebView in iOS

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview, ios10.3

I have a requirement of loading Javascript files through `HTML` file. I have structured files in order shown in below screenshot.

[image]

`HTML` head tag contains the `Javascript` files to call as below:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script type="text/javascript" src="AjaxCapturer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="authenticate.js"></script>
</head>
```

So I have been using `UIWebView` to load the page and its loading properly as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Now if I run same thing using `WKWebView` then the page is keep on loading as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

`Javascript` files are firing (added alert) but page does not load in `WKWebView`. Below is my code logic:

```
-(void)loadWebVW{

    WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKPreferences *pref = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
    pref.javaScriptEnabled = YES;
    pref.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
    config.preferences = pref;

    CGRect vwFrame = CGRectMake(10, 80, 300, 480);
    WKWebView *webVW = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:vwFrame configuration:config];
    [self.view addSubview:webVW];
    webVW.navigationDelegate = self;
    webVW.UIDelegate = self;

    NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"offline_Forms"
                                                         ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                  error:nil];
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/JavaScript",
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
    [webVW loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseUrl];

    //or//

    // [webVW loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlPath]]];

}
```

Do we need to add any additional stuff to load it in `WKWebView`. Please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @randombits, Can you please help on this...

Comment: did you got solution for this @Ganesh Guturi? Because I am also facing same issue, if you already fixed it, can you post the answer? Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer below @AnilkumariOSdeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is a known issue in `iOS` 10.3 and fixed later in `iOS` 10.3.2, see link 
[from Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71653?start=0&tstart=0) for more information. Sometimes I feel that the same issue being existed in `Simulator` but works fine in physical devices. So make sure every time you verify `WKWebView` functionality in physical device.