# javascript embedded in html not running in wkwebview

Tags: javascript, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am implementing wkwebview in an app that was using UIWebView. I am unable to get javascript to execute when pointing to a local html file that has the javascript embedded within it. The javascript is stripped to do a simple alert and load a basic google map. None of that is getting executed. Do I need to run a local server? GCDWebserver..

I should add, the html/javascript works in safari, google browser no problem.

Solutions attempted include:
1. AppTransportSecuritySettings AllowArbitrary loads.
2. ViewController.swift webview.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
3. This question addresses the issue and says is was fixed in iOS 10.3 [Load Javascript files through HTML file on WKWebView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371386/load-javascript-files-through-html-file-on-wkwebview-in-ios)  The simulator is running 12.1
4. This question also addresses the issue with an answer of requiring GCDWebserver to be able to execute javascript using wkwebview. [WKWebView not executing any js code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170840/wkwebview-not-executing-any-js-code) This however was also solved in a laster version of iOS.  Here is some code:

```swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    //@IBOutlet var googleMap: WKWebView!
    var webview: WKWebView!

     override func loadView() {
         webview = WKWebView()
         webview.navigationDelegate = self
         view = webview
     }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let url = URL(string: "https://schallerf1.com")!
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "www")!
        webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webview.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webview.load(request)
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
                <style>
                    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                     * element that contains the map. */
                #map {
                    height: 100%;
                }
                /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
                html, body {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
    <body>
        <b>WHYYYYYYYYYY!!!!</b>
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%;" id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var name = "TESTTESTTEST";
            alert('code: '    + name + '\n');
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                          center: {lat: 39.976068, lng: -83.003297},
                                          zoom: 8
                                          });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

None of the javascript works, I should get an alert and a simple google map should display. Do I need to look into the local web server GCDWebserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling your javascript in this `WKNavigationDelegate` method, which is called when the webview finishes loading.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("initMap()", completionHandler: { (value, err) in
        // Handle response here.
    })
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're calling two different `webview.load()` requests - maybe don't do that?

Comment: Thank you Jake for taking the time to answer.  I implemented the WkNavigationDelegate as suggested.  Still do not appear to be executing javascript.  My index.html file does a window.load on main.html. Thus the initMap() function is not found from main.html.  I added a test function into index.html
with an alert `alert('code:'  + name + ' \n')` and a console.log `console.log("i should see this in the console");`,  but they are not getting executed even though the function is found. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try printing out `value` and `err` in the `completionHandler` of that function above (`evaluateJavaScript`). What does it say?

Comment: Hi Jake.  Value returns nothing, err returns nil.    Here is the output from the console; Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: initMap, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=8, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=file:///Users/schallerf1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/30497599-5839-4A2C-87F7-CC2D8F4F16DA/HistOrigin.app/www/index.html, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})
nil

Comment: Key message here is "Can't find variable: initMap" - it's not finding your JS `function` anywhere. Make sure you're loading the correct source. Try removing the `subdirectory: "www"` from your resource url. Instead: `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")!`

Comment: Removed subdirectory www as suggested. got this error on that line: _Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_  . To clarify, index.html does window.load on main.html. main.html contains html, and map javascript.  Added javascript includes from the larger project, they seem to load as seen in this image.  I see maps.googleapis.com in red. Im thinking this could be a google maps api key issue, but I have already tried keys specifically for an iOS app and a open key. ![Web Inspector image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GG3gF4REGIlXGq9rhD97eS_wIh5hkJVI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: oops I added wrong image this is the correct one ![web inspector view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3zsUR8Q--mu1NgmdFcmioo0w1w2D7iM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why not just load main.html instead of index.html in the first place? That sounds like your problem.

Comment: Jake, your suggestion of eliminating the index.htm file to point directly to the main.html file is the answer to this question.  Im on to the next obstacle now, but that is a new question.  Thank you very much for your time and effort.